# Can I setup Synology DSM to only one disk and then pull in data to setup RAID 1 afterwards?

Tags: network-attached-storage, synology

**Given situation:**

**Synlogy** with 2x1TB (disks not further needed)

MyCloud with **2x3TB** (Raid level 1)

**Goal:**

**I want want to run the 3TB disks in the synology.**

When I switched disks Synology wants to install DSM and warns of losing any data.

**Question:**

Can I

- start with only inserting 1x3TB in the Synology and install DSM by accepting to lose all the data on that disk
- subsequently pull in the data by pulling in the data from the other disc (by using an HDD Docking station)
- then putting in the second disk

Will that plan work?
What would I have to consider probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work. When you install DSM onto the 1st hard drive, you need to make sure you use "SHR" as the volume / RAID type.

Synology "Storage Manager" is where you manage your disks, volumes and storage pools. Once DSM is installed on the first drive, do exactly what you said: Copy all of the data over from the MyCloud. Once the data is finished copying, insert the 2nd hard drive into the NAS.

To add it to the RAID, navigate into Storage Manager, select the storage pool you created when you first installed DSM, and click Add Drive.

See https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_expand_add_disk for Synology's specific instructions.

All of that said, while this SHOULD work, I would highly recommend that you have a backup of this data somewhere else in the event that something goes wrong. Syncing and copying that much data creates a lot of wear and tear on the drives.